# Integrating fast image cache by path

Tags: ios, image, caching, tableview

i want to integrate fast image cache for my app. The images needs to be loaded from a url and in tableview cells like facebook feeds. i am not able to understand the fast image cache documentation provided by path. Can anyone help me to integrate this in my app. The documentation and library is here : https://github.com/path/FastImageCache

Thanks

Comment: did you got the steps to integrate the FastImageCache?